# How to fix btrfs error according to thermal directory

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, btrfs

I'm new to ubuntu and I think something went wrong while performing apt upgrades. The unattended upgrades fail due to this error message:

> dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-headers
> /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-112/drivers/thermal/ti-soc-thermal/Makefile.dpkg-tmp
> kann nicht auf sichere Weise entfernt werden: Input/output error

As I wanted to remove this file manually, I followed the path to /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-112/drivers. Unfortunately I'm not able to open the thermal directory due to this error message while trying to open it.

[btrfs error while trying to access thermal directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kke9x.png)

I'm not unable to install updates at all, but this one fail every day. Is there any possibility to fix this error ?

Comment: You might want to translate the error message to English.
I guess it's sth like `dpkg: error when processing packet linux-headers (path) cannot be safely deleted: Input/ouput error`?
You can try repeating the command with LC_ALL=C prepended

Comment: FYI, it's best to only ask your question in one Stack Exchange community.  Taking the community tours and reading the help will assist you to select the best community.